# Detect if web application is opened in outlook-add-in

Tags: javascript, angularjs, outlook, office365, office-addins

I'm struggeling to check if my hosted web application is opened by a browser or in the Outlook 2013/2016 client.

I have one web application, which must provide different features for users in a browser and in the Outlook 2013/2016 sandboxed iframe.

**My approach**

with AngularJS in the mainController:

```
$rootScope.isIFrame = false;
if (window.location !== window.parent.location) {
  // The page is in an iframe
  $rootScope.isIFrame = true;
};
$log.debug('isIFrame: ' + $rootScope.isIFrame);
```

Comment: i hate to suggest this, but maybe checking `navigator.userAgent` would suit your needs.

Comment: do you have an idea which useragent is used by outlooks sandboxed iframe?

Comment: no, just dump it out to the screen with js: `document.body.innerHTML=navigator.userAgent`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Office.context.mailbox.diagnostics.hostName:](https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/Office.context.mailbox.diagnostics.html#hostName)

> Gets a string that represents the name of the host application.
>        A string that can be one of the following values: `Outlook`, `Mac Outlook` or `OutlookWebApp`.